# Change page_entries_info text in ruby on rails (en.yml not taking affect)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've added this to my `config/locales/en.yml` file:

```
en:
  hello: "Hello world"
  will_paginate:
    page_entries_info:
      single_page:
        zero:  "No %{model} found"
        one:   "Displayingggg 1 %{model}"
        other: "Displayingggggg all %{count} %{model}"
      single_page_html:
        zero:  "No %{model} found"
        one:   "Displayingggg <b>1</b> %{model}"
        other: "Displayingggg <b>all&nbsp;%{count}</b> %{model}"
      multi_page: "Displaddying %{model} %{from} - %{to} of %{count} in total"
      multi_page_html: "Displayingggggg %{model} <b>%{from}&nbsp;-&nbsp;%{to}</b> of <b>%{count}</b> in totalddd"
```

I added the extra g's and such just to test. It's not taking affect.

I'm doing `<%= page_entries_info(@properties) %>` in the templates which outputs: `Displaying properties 11 - 20 of 29 in total`

Edit: this is using Kaminari. not sure if that matters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it's different when you use Kaminari:

```
en:
  helpers:
    page_entries_info:
      more_pages:
        display_entries: "Showing %{first}-%{last} of %{total} %{entry_name}"
```

takes affect